# Changing cpp code to c (struct type)

Tags: c++, c

Could help about making that code pure C.

```
struct edge
{
    char key;
    char values[5];
};

edge* a = new edge[9];
```

Comment: This code won't even compile as C++. You have to provide a minimal working code example and ask your question.

Comment: just change the last line to `struct edge *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * 9)`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to create nine instances of `struct edge`? Also, CPP means C PreProcessor, but you mean C++ which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/612350/1214731 is a good resource for this kind of question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typedef struct
{  
    char key;
    char values[5];
} edge ;

edge *a = malloc(9 * sizeof(edge)) ;
```

This should do it

Comment: @Rckt: You're declaring `edge* a` in global scope (which has static storage duration) and can only be initialized with constants, i.e. `1` or `"hello"`, etc. (This is another C quirk).

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with this code. What exactly is the structure of the rest of your program?

Comment: I've fixed it. But I need to create nine instances of struct edge. Is it possible?

Comment: The above code does exactly that. It assigns enough space for 9 elements of edge. If you want to access the nth element, just use
*(edge + n - 1) ;

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark, and assume that you actually don't need dynamic memory allocation at all. In that case, the C version is:

```
struct edge
{
    char key;
    char values[5];
};

struct edge a[9];
```

Remember, in C++ you don't need `new` to create objects, you only need `new` if you want to *dynamically* create objects.

If my guess is correct, the above will work perfectly for you. If my guess is incorrect, then you'll get an error in your program on a line like:

```
a = foo;
```